# PHP code read and writes to file fine UNTIL i compare a substring

Tags: php, file-io, substring

The following PHP code works to read one file and write the same content into another file:

```
<?php

$input = @fopen("./temp.def", "r");
$output = @fopen("./temp.tpc","w");

if ($input) {

    while (!feof($input)) {
        $buffer = fgets($input);
        fputs($output, $buffer);
    }
    if (!feof($input)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }

    fclose($input);
    fclose($output);

}
```

But when I add code to replace some content based off of whether or not a substring is some specific text it doesn’t work. Here’s the code for that:

```
<?php

$input = @fopen("./temp.def", "r");
$output = @fopen("./temp.tpc","w");

if ($input) {

    while (!feof($input)) {
        $buffer = fgets($input);

        //check to see if it is a `row`  line
        $isrow = mb_substr($buffer, 0, 5, 'UTF-8');
        if ($isrow == "row=:") {
            $data = str_ireplace("row=:", "base=:[loc^nb]" . chr(10) . "row=:", $buffer);
            else {
                $data =  $buffer;
            }
        }

        fputs($output, $data);
    }
    if (!feof($input)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }

    fclose($input);
    fclose($output);

}
```

The only thing changed in the code is the added part, highlighted  in yellow, and the variable name change, highlighted in blue...

[color-highlighted code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FyE5.png)

Comment: `} else {` maybe...

Comment: You have a misplaced brace. There isn't one between the if statement and `else`, and there's a brace floating around below that..

Comment: I am not possitive here, but is `str_ireplace()` Multi Byte character set aware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some weird bracing going on there.  Try:

```
if ($isrow == "row=:") {
    $data = str_ireplace("row=:", "base=:[loc^nb]" . chr(10) . "row=:", $buffer);
} else {
    $data =  $buffer;
}
```